# Show a text-box when selecting one color and hide other same time

Tags: jquery, html-select, show-hide

I am having an issue getting the second text-box to hide when selecting the first one. and vice a versa. I think I may not have the code written correctly.

```
  <select id = 'color2' name = 'dept' onchange = "

            if ($('#color2').val() == 'others')
                    {
                      $('#color_a').show();
                      $('#color_b').hide();
                    } 

            else($('#color2').val() == 'blue')
                    {
                      $('#color_b').show();

                      $('color_a').hide();
                    } 

                   ">


  <option value="">Select a Field</option>
  <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
  <option value="others">others</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't inline JavaScript like that please

Comment: Firstly, this should really be in a separate script tag, or file, and being called on $('#color2').change(). Secondly, the hide color_a in the else statement should have a # before it if it's an ID.

Comment: Also, the else part of an if/else doesn't take a parameter, you'll want an else if.

Comment: thank you got it working

Comment: I am going to move it into a function I was inline just for simplicity. MCMXCII thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your element selections on top and assign them to a var, that way you don't have to traverse the DOM every time you click on the element to select the other elements.

Put it in a script tag, it will save a lot of headaches.

```js
(function($){
 $(function(){
   var select = $('#color2'),
       colorA = $('#color_a'),
       colorB = $('#color_b');
   
   // hide all colors
   $('.color').hide();
   
   select.on('change', function(){
     $('.color').hide();
     
     if (select.val() == 'others'){
       colorA.show();
     }
     else if (select.val() == 'blue') {
       colorB.show();
     }
     
   });
   
 })
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="color2" name='dept'>
  <option value="">Select a Field</option>
  <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
  <option value="others">others</option>
</select>

<div id="color_a" class="color">Color A (others)</div>
<div id="color_b" class="color">Color B (blue)</div>
```

Comment: this is not working the way i need it to check inline bellow

Comment: i see its working on the snippet so i can give you credit for it